# Sinch video call hangup crash android when not received by receiver

Tags: android, video, sdk, call, sinch

I am using the video calling feature of the **Sinch** and facing one issue. The situation is like this. For example I am login as a user **A**. Try to call user **B**. Immediately hang up before user **B** pick up the call. And than User **A** try to stop the **Sinch Client**. After a two second I got the **Crash**. The **error logs** are below.

```
W/sinch-android-rtc: webrtc: (mediasession.cc:362): Duplicate id found. Reassigning from 101 to 125
D/DefaultHttpService: Http request to https://sandbox.sinch.com/V1/Session
D/AudioTrackJni: Terminate@[tid=13743]
D/AudioTrackJni: StopPlayout@[tid=13743]
D/AudioTrackJni: ~dtor@[tid=13743]
D/AudioTrackJni: Terminate@[tid=13743]
D/AudioTrackJni: StopPlayout@[tid=13743]
E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in ../../../talk/app/webrtc/androidvideocapturer.cc, line 155
# Check failed: !running_
#
#
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13739 (Sinch Worker Th)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
[ 08-01 12:41:08.376 14347:14347 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf3e9b860, tid 14347
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You fond a bug, the work around is to not stop the client. Usually you start and stop the client as a service. And if you want to receive calls you should never stop it. you should keep it running.

However we added it to bugs to fix because we should not of course crash.

Comment: Please do me a favor and let me know once this get fixed.